# How can I see and access folders in Outlook 2010 which have disappeared from view?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

When I initially installed Office Home and Business 2010 I set up a number of folders within Outlook.  These were visible and accessible for a period of time then I noticed they had vanished. I have tried searching for them but they are nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to click on the "folder list" icon on the bottom left to expand the folder view.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple commands you can try to get them back (run form a command prompt, with Outlook closed):

- `outlook.exe /resetfolders`

Restores missing folders for the default delivery location.

- `outlook.exe /resetnavpane`

Clears and regenerates the Navigation Pane for the current profile.